# passing ng-repeat to a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am trying to create a wrapper directive for select/dropdowns... but not able to pass the ngRepeat to the directive

```
return {
    scope: { options: '=', ngModel: '=', ngRepeat: '=', textField: '@', valueField: '@' },
    required: ['ngModel', 'ngRepeat', 'textField', 'valueField', '^form'],
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: compileFunction,
};
```

and the corresponding html is:

```
    html += '<select data-ng-model="ngModel" name="myfield" >' +
                ' <option value=""></option> ' +
                ' <option data-ng-repeat="ngRepeat" value="valueField">{{textField}}</option>' +
            '</select> ';
```

but getting an error:

```
Expected ngRepeat in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got 'ngRepeat'.
```

any idea why???

**EDIT**
[PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/jdGY4I0qtO27flp7jLb5?p=preview)

added a plunker link

Comment: @DavinTryon tried that.. but not working.. btw added plunker link

Comment: can someone please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should receive `ngRepeat` using `@` and not `=` as you want to execute it after it is being placed and also the directive should not be able to change the value of the `ngRepeat` expression...